# QML creating Text element takes long time

Tags: performance, qt, text, qml

I noticed that creating Text element in QML takes long time.
For an example:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 320
    height: 640
    color: "yellow"
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 1000
        delegate: Component {
            Rectangle {
                width: parent.width
                height: 50
                color: index % 2 == 0 ? "#eee" : "#ddd"
                Text {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    font { family: "Helvetica"; pixelSize: 15 }
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    text: "9"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In QML Profiler this is result:

```
Location        Type        Time in Percent Total Time  Calls   Mean Time   Median Time Longest Time    Shortest Time   Details
<program>                   100.00 %        730.664 ms  1       730.664 ms  730.664 ms  730.664 ms      730.664 ms      Main Program
main.qml:17     Create      82.33 %         601.544 ms  706     852.045 µs  46.227 µs   536.645 ms      7.777 µs        QtQuick/Text
main.qml:9      Create      76.37 %         557.974 ms  2       278.987 ms  557.793 ms  557.793 ms      181.747 µs      QtQuick/ListView
main.qml:4      Create      15.04 %         109.901 ms  2       54.951 ms   109.520 ms  109.520 ms      380.668 µs      QtQuick.Window/Window
main.qml:13     Create      4.90 %          35.826 ms   706     50.744 µs   14.842 µs   20.833 ms       0.438 µs        QtQuick/Rectangle
main.qml:18     Binding     0.74 %          5.397 ms    353     15.288 µs   15.704 µs   86.770 µs       4.841 µs        anchors.fill: parent
main.qml:16     Binding     0.58 %          4.224 ms    353     11.964 µs   11.686 µs   171.614 µs      4.813 µs        color: index % 2 == 0 ? "#eee" : "#ddd"
main.qml:18     JavaScript  0.40 %          2.952 ms    353     8.361 µs    8.689 µs    22.030 µs       2.597 µs        expression for fill
main.qml:16     JavaScript  0.32 %          2.351 ms    353     6.660 µs    6.289 µs    165.754 µs      2.598 µs        expression for color
main.qml:14     Binding     0.26 %          1.870 ms    354     5.282 µs    5.301 µs    31.643 µs       2.261 µs        width: parent.width
main.qml:14     JavaScript  0.19 %          1.419 ms    354     4.007 µs    4.066 µs    12.325 µs       1.591 µs        expression for width
main.qml:1      Compile     0.10 %          759.314 µs  1       759.314 µs  759.314 µs  759.314 µs      759.314 µs      main.qml
main.qml:10     Binding     0.01 %          41.470 µs   1       41.470 µs   41.470 µs   41.470 µs       41.470 µs       anchors.fill: parent
main.qml:10     JavaScript  0.00 %          22.325 µs   1       22.325 µs   22.325 µs   22.325 µs       22.325 µs       expression for fill
main.qml:12     Create      0.00 %          3.321 µs    1       3.321 µs    3.321 µs    3.321 µs        3.321 µs        <component>
```

As you can see, creating Text element takes very high time.
In another project with some Text in delegate, this is the result:

```
Location                Type        Time in Percent Total Time  Calls   Mean Time   Median Time Longest Time    Shortest Time   Details
PostLikeAndMark.qml:41  Create      79.20 %         1.261 s     46      27.406 ms   60.427 µs   1.257 s         7.124 µs        QtQuick/Text
```

Is there any solution to work around this problem?

**UPDATE**
It seems that this problem might be related to font family in some situations.
For a new recent project, I found that using some font families introduces this problem. (`Segue UI`)
Changing font family to some other fonts such as `Myriad Pro`, solved the problem.

Comment: Which Qt version, platform, graphics card, etc.? https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43012 and https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42853 might be relevant.

Comment: MacBookPro, Mac OS X 10.11.3, Nvidia GT 650M, RAM 16G, CPU Intel i7 2.7 GHz 4Core. No! both bugs are irrelevant.

Comment: this should be due to a known bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-36587.

Comment: it is OSX-specific. From what I gather, the number of system-installed font has an influence on it as it has to do with the font database.

Comment: No, that bug is for another issue and is not related to QML/QtQuick. I noticed that there is not change if I use an embedded font.

Answer (score 0):

I found, that by setting the textFormat property where possible, a relevant increase of overall performance could be achieved.
Depends on your implementation of course.

Got the hint from:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html#text-elements

Comment: It seems that a tiny performance gained.