# Confused on QML profiler information?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml, profiler

As you can see in this Profiler Statistics, it's just a simple Text. How can it take 28.04% of total time? Could someone let me know how to read this?

[image: see statistics here]

Comment: Might be the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/q/35699871/6165833